# WPF - Binding events to class methods of Item in ItemControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, event-binding

I'm a bit new to WPF/XAML (though I've learnt C#) and would really appreciate any help for my question. I did look around other posts and google for a while but I can't seem to find a satisfactory or detailed answer to get me going on with my project. Please look below for details. Thanks you in advance!

### Objective

I have a class called Tile that consists of a few properties and an event handler.
I also have an ItemControl that has a button (as by the DataTemplate), and whose ItemSource is a collection of Tiles.

Now, I want to bind the "Click" event of the Button so as to invoke the Event Handler method defined in the class Tile.

In other words when I click the button of any item in the ItemControl, the method handler of the corresponding Tile instance (from the collection) must be invoked. How would I tackle this problem?

Below is the entire code, simplified to avoid distraction:

#### XAML

```
<Window x:Class="SampleWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">

    <!-- Make a ItemControl for "Tile"s. -->
    <ItemsControl x:Name="TileList">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- Wire the click event of this Button 
                 to event handler in the Tile class. -->
                <Button Content="Show"></Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

</Window>
```

#### CODE-BEHIND

```
namespace SampleWPF
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ObservableCollection<Tile> tiles;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Adding some sample data for testing.
            tiles = new ObservableCollection<Tile>();
            tiles.Add(new Tile("Item 1"));
            tiles.Add(new Tile("Item 2"));

            TileList.ItemsSource = tiles;
        }
    }

    public class Tile : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string Data
        { /* Accessors and PropertyNotifiers */ }

        public Tile(string data)
        { /* Initializing and assigning "Data" */ }

        // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation...
        // { ... }

        // This event handler should be bound to the Button's "Click" event
        // in the DataTemplate of the Item.
        public void ShowButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Viewing item from: " + this.Data);
        }
    }
}
```

Hence, if I click the first "Show" button, the output should be "Viewing item from: Item 1" and if I click the second "Show" Button, the output should be "Viewing item from: Item 2".

So what is the recommended/efficient way to do this? Is my code inappropriate for this requirement?

Comment: AnyAnswer.SatisfyYou() ? "mark as answer" : "ask for help";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start with some basics:
Don't assign itemsource in codeBehind - use Binding like this:

```
<Controll ItemSource="{Binding MyObservableCollection}"/>
```

There are many ways You can achieve this. I think that using this.Data is not the best solution for this.
For example if Your tail have ID or something You can assign this id to button CommandParameter like below

```
<Button CommanParameter="{Binding Path=ID}" Click="ShowButton_Click"/>
```

And then  in Your button_click event u can 'catch' this like this:

```
public void ShowButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int ID = int.Parse(((Button)sender).CommandParameter.ToString());
}
```

EDIT

To use this binding You need to set DataContext. You can do this in ctor like this:

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Adding some sample data for testing.
        tiles = new ObservableCollection<Tile>();
        tiles.Add(new Tile("Item 1"));
        tiles.Add(new Tile("Item 2"));
        // below You are setting a datacontext of a MainWindow to itself
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
```

ANOTHER EDIT

Let's assume Your tail class have property called ID. If You bound this ID to Button.CommandParameter You can later retrieve the tile with linq like this:

```
public void ShowButton_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int MyId = int.Parse(((Button)sender).CommandParameter.ToString());
   Tile TileIWasSearchingFor = (from t in tiles where t.ID == MyId select t).First();
// do something with tile You found
}
```

Comment: Hmm, okay so then I need to search the collection for the Tile instance that matches the ID and then access it finally? And why does my window show blank when I set <ItemControl ItemSource="{Binding tiles}"/> .... </ItemControl> ?

Comment: I'll answer by updating my answer

Comment: Okay cool, that worked. And am I correct about my understanding of "ID" as per my first comment?

Comment: This LinQ statement might not work(You may need to cast this to tile). If U will need more help just ask.

Comment: Well followed along your lines, but I guess LINQ could be avoided..? Check out my answer below.

Comment: You're right :) Your answer is very suitable for this question, it includes everything OP needed :)

Answer (score 2):

Event handlers are the wrong approach - use `Commands` and more importantly MVVM.

As I can see that you are new (and probably from a `WinForms` or `ASP.NET` background) you should read this blog to understand how your thinking needs to change - this is the most important part to understand before tackling `WPF`: http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/10/12/switching-from-winforms-to-wpfmvvm/

You should also read Kent Boogart's blog on how MVVM works from base principles: http://kentb.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/view-models-pocos-versus.html

Comment: You are totally right, but MVVM is kinda hard for begginers. I usually suggest to get some basics and then go with MVVM.

Comment: The assumption is that this person is already be comfortable with another UI technology as they're immediately asking about event handlers (which is standard interaction paradigm for ASP.NET/WinForms). For someone with no UI experience at all, I would also suggest a different approach.

Comment: Well your thinking have 'wider range' i see. Can't argue with that ofc. Upvoting Your answer since it may interest him and help him in future.

Comment: Hey well yeah the posts are really helpful... Esp the "WinForms to WPF" one :D Thanks a ton! Upvoted. Well I am now looking around for more posts on Commands in WPF and I'll comment again if I need further help?

Comment: Sure. Kent's blog on `Commands` pretty much covers the majority of what you need to know especially `DelegateCommand`. And once you're comfortable with the base concepts, then look at PRISM - it's the gold standard of WPF MVVM development. Also don't forget to mark a right answer at some point too. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well since my requirement was rather "simple", I've managed a work around, avoiding commands. Thanks to the answer here by MajkeloDev:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/27419974/3998255 for guidance.

This is the final event handler:

```
public void ShowButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Tile requestingTile = (sender as Button).DataContext as Tile;
        if(requestingTile != null)
            MessageBox.Show("Viewing item from: " + this.Data); 
            // Or whatever else you want to do with the object...
    }
```

Also, adding the ItemSource as a XAML attribute:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="TileList" ItemsSource="{Binding tiles}">
```

And setting DataContext in constructor of MainWindow:

```
public MainWindow()
{ 
    this.DataContext = this;
    // Whatever else you want to do...
}
```

Well it works as required.

Comment: Its okay but I don't like "this.Data" part. Imagine a class with very big amount of  code, would it be readable ?

Comment: Uh no well as I had mentioned I just wrote that to keep it simple. My actually requirements are different, I needed a way to get access to the right instance for the required operations. However, yes you're right, if the data is large it wouldn't make sense (I'm not _actually_ doing that in my program).